# Concrete5 block can't be able to edit

Tags: php, content-management-system, block, concrete5

If i try to edit one of my blog. I m getting this info on the popup,

**This block was copied from another location. Editing it will create a new instance of it.**

And also I can't able to edit any things in this block.

This is the error block of Form with Paypal payment,

[image]

How to fix this issue?

Thanks

Comment: It looks like you may need to adjust your permissions to include chmod for your php files.  I will see if I can play with this today.  How about creating a new block in place of your copy of for Paypal?  While handy, the copy/paste function for copying blocks may not always work..  You should be able to simply create a new block rather than creating a copy/link to the old one.

Comment: Also, did you query the Concrete5 site?  You do not appear to be alone in this.  For example - http://www.concrete5.org/developers/bugs/5.6.0.1/unable-to-get-permission-key-to-write/-/copyToCurrentDefault/

Answer (score 1):

I will show you..  Updated..

Go into concrete edit mode..

OK.  You are using a Paypal add-on Block..  Since I don't have that one, I will use a substitute..  I have MegaMenu - It does not have the options for HTML either.  There are many tabs for settings and I would have to assume the PayPal block has similar settings/changes available.  Not necessarily a permanaent change, but enough of a change that you can break the copy of..  Maybe - If this is not the case..  Why not create a new block using the add-on for PayPal?  I know that is not ideal..  The other option you can do is use a Stack.

Editing the copied block..
[image]
We should have a checkbox, a form field that we can change or edit to save..  Once saved, it should update and break the copy of..

OK..  Maybe you are not seeing the exact same thing..  What is the block in the MarketPlace?  Can you provide me the URL for it?  To see if I can duplicate/replicate your issue?

Locate the block that is copied..  Note: the very light dotted pink line around the block..
[image]

Put the block in Edit Mode..
[image]

If you cannot edit the page directly, look for the HTML link and update the content of the page...  and update..
[image]

Comment: ok this one is correct for normal block. In my Form with paypal payment, there is no option for html

Comment: I update my question with screen shot. There is no option for html view

Comment: Did you not read my update/comments?  My update also includes a block that does not have HTML as an option.  I also provide a couple of options to work around this..  I also asked you for the URL in the Marketplace for the add-on.